# Simulating light absorption in Photosynthesis through Quantum computing

Tags: qiskit, programming, photonics, quantum-biology

[image]

Basically, I want to simulate the above photosystem process of light absorption. Above is a diagram of laser beams shot into antenna pigment molecules and traveling to the reaction center. Two theories surround the laser path: Random and shortest distance. The latter is more feasible.

[image]

My goal is to simulate the quantum effect behind this process regardless of which pigment molecule the light is being shot at. I came across this github repo on [Quantum programmable gate arrays](https://github.com/fancompute/qpga) so I want to know how to remodel it to simulate the above process.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Interesting question...however, could you please add more details? For example links to papers concerning photosynthesis modelling as there would be only few biologists on this site.

Comment: I think you should search for random quantum walk algorithms

Comment: @Mauricio The path is the shortest distance, not random.

Comment: Try using PennyLane: https://pennylane.ai/

Comment: @isaac PennyLane is a library. What exactly am I using therE?

Comment: @oo92 any references to "shortest distance"? The point of "random walks" here is not to simulate random trajectories, but to understand how a quantum system can go from point A to point B even if there are many paths available (see the image you provided).

Comment: @oo92 PennyLane is a quantum computing, machine learning, and chemistry package :) I'm not sure what you'll need for your project specifically, but I'm sure it can be of use!