# Modeling light transfer through every path with superpositioning

Tags: circuit-construction, hadamard, superposition, quantum-biology

So I asked a [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28550/simulating-light-absorption-in-photosynthesis-through-quantum-computing) about this topic earlier but since then, I did more digging into this problem.

Researchers at Berkeley experimented with a theory of photosynthesis happening using Quantum superposition. Basically, the absorbed electron travels through every single Chlorophyll, as opposed to random paths or the shortest path, to reach near 100% efficiency. The experiment is called 2D Fourier Transform Electronic Spectroscopy. They probed into the inner structure of the photosynthetic complex. They fired 3 successive pulses of laser light into it, which generated signals, which were then picked up by the detector.

My question/idea/early hypothesis is this: If I want to model this process in a circuit, would that look like a series of Hadamard gates? The exciton travels through every chlorophyll until it reaches the reaction centre. Since this is superposition, my first idea was that it would involve a series of Hadamard gates.

This is where my inspiration came from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zc9Xk99gCr4